# 2D Chunked Grid Fast Access

Tags: optimization, position, 2d, chunks

I am working on a program that stores some data in cells (small structs) and processes each one individually. The processing step accesses the 4 neighbors of the cell (2D). I also need them partitioned in chunks because the cells might be distributed randomly trough a very large surface, and having a large grid with mostly empty cells would be a waste. I also use the chunks for some other optimizations (skipping processing of chunks based on some conditions).

I currently have a hashmap of "chunk positions" to chunks (which are the actual fixed size grids). The position is calculated based on the chunk size (like Minecraft). The issue is that, when processing the cells in every chunk, I lose a lot of time doing a lookup to get the chunk of the neighbor. Most of the time, the neighbor is in the same chunk we are processing, so I did a check to prevent looking up a chunk if the neighbor is in the same chunk we are processing.

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: This is very hard to help you with the provided information. That being said the data structure seems not to be suited for local access. There are other data structure better for that but whether they will perform better is very dependent of the actual computation which is not sufficiently described here. For example, building the static graph can be very efficient to find neighbours but this require a full pass and assume there are no dynamic modifications. Quad-tree can also help a lot or multi-level grids. It looks like you want to do a basic AMR and your problem is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lacks some details, but hopefully you can employ a solution such as this:

- Process the interior of a chunk (ie excluding the edges) separately. During this phase, the neighbours are for sure in the same chunk, so you can do this with zero chunk-lookups. The difference between this and doing a check to see whether a chunk-lookup is necessary, is that there is not even a check. The check is implicit in the loop bounds.
- For edges, you can do a *few* chunk lookups and reuse the result across the edge.

This approach gets worse with smaller chunk sizes, or if you need access to neighbours further than 1 step away. It breaks down entirely in case of random access to cells. If you need to maintain a strict ordering for the processing of cells, this approach can still be used with minor modifications by rearranging it (there wouldn't be strict "process the interior" phase, but you would still have a nice inner loop with zero chunk-lookups).

Such techniques are common in general in cases where the boundary has different behaviour than the interior.